# Microsoft SQL connection with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-connection, opencart

Im going to setup an OpenCart ecommerce website, which is going to integrate with  Microsoft SQL Database.

The OpenCart platform is going to use MySQL Server. How can i get the intergration between those two databases?

The Microsoft SQL, is having the products that I want to insert into my OpenCart Platform and the only access from Microsoft SQL is SQL Commands (not any API).

Comment: How frequently will you need to insert products in to OpenCart?
Will you need to regularly update stock levels or will it be quite rare?
Is the sync only 1 way i.e. MSSQL to MySQL? More info about what you're trying to achieve would help.

Comment: Its going to be one way. I want to get all products from specific categories, every week. So every week I will run a cron job for the integration. The stock is not in our options.

Answer (score 1):

As this doesn't have to happen very frequently, why not write a PHP script on the OpenCart site that connects to the MSSQL database and gets the data it needs in to an array, then loops over this and adds it to the OpenCart MySQL database?

Comment: I was thinking about that. Thank you Paul for your strait answer.